# Extension of Central limit theorem

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

In CLT, we require each $X_{n}$ to be independent and identically distributed. Then we have $\frac{Sn}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges weakly to $N(0,1)$.

But if we have the sequence ${Xn}$ to be standard normal distribution but not necessarily independent. Then what happens to $\frac{Sn}{\sqrt{n}}$?

I know that it can converge to many different values, but what are the possible outcomes? Is it possible to converge to all normal distributions with mean $0$, for example to $N(0,2)$?

My idea is to use the characteristic function. We have $E_{X}(e^{it\sqrt{n}X})$, where $X$ stands for standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$. Then we should compare it with characteristic functions of other normal distributions but I've no idea how to do it

Comment: If $X_{2n - 1} = X_1$ and $X_{2n} = -X_1$, then $S_{2n - 1} = X_1$, $S_{2n} = 0$. So $S_n/\sqrt{n} \to 0$ a.s..

Comment: If we add independent then the answer would be the same as CLT. But is it possible to have it converges to $N(0,2)$ or $N(0,1/2)$ in distribution? Is there a more general result for it to converge to other normal distributions?

Comment: You may find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Dependent_processes) helpful for extensions of CLT under dependencies. Under the right conditions, you get $N(0,1)$ asymptotically if the sum is appropriately standardized. Equivalently, you can get $N(0,\sigma^2)$ by simply standardizing differently (e.g. recall in the classical CLT, $\sqrt n (\bar X_n-\mu)\to_d N(0,\sigma^2)$).